# Powershell match array and pipe to process

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to find all hotfixes declared in the $unhotfix array, then uninstall each if found.

```
$unhotfix ="KB2966826","KB2966827","KB2966828"

Get-Hotfix | ? (HotFixId -match $unhotfix) | `
${wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:$_.HotfixId /norestart /log} | wait-process
```

Using the following works for comparing one value:

```
Get-Hotfix | ? (HotFixId -match "KB2966826") | select HotFixId
```

However, I am missing something about matching arrays

```
Get-Hotfix | ? (HotFixId -match $unhotfixid) | select HotFixId
```

Gives no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-Hotfix` has an `-Id parameter` that accepts an array of hotfix names.

```
Get-Hotfix -Id $unhotfix
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-HotFix | 
    Where-Object {$unhotfix.Contains($_.HotFixId)}
```

What this does it tests for the array of hotfix listings, and if it finds the `HotFixId` in that array, it'll return the matching hotfixes.

Comment: The `Contains()` method is case-sensitive. I'd recommend using the `-contains` operator instead.